# What are some best practices for file I/O in C?

Tags: c, file, io

I'm writing a fairly basic program for personal use but I really want to make sure I use good practices, especially if I decide to make it more robust later on or something.

For all intents and purposes, the program accepts some input files as arguments, opens them using `fopen()` read from the files, does stuff with that information, and then saves the output as a few different files in a subfolder. eg, if the program is in `~/program` then the output files are saved in `~/program/csv/`

I just output directly to the files, for example  `output = fopen("./csv/output.csv", "w");`, print to it with `fprintf(output,"%f,%f", data1, data2);` in a loop, and then close with `fclose(output);`  and I just feel like that is bad practice.

Should I be saving it in a temp directory wile it's being written to and then moving it when it's finished? Should I be using more advanced file i/o libraries? Am I just completely overthinking this?

Comment: For something this simple, I think you are overthinking it.  If you are the only process (or thread) writing to the file(s), then there is no need for extra work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] before too long.  This might be a question without a precise answer.  For the most part, what you're doing is fine.  A temporary directory is probably overkill.  You might want to check that `fclose()` works; if not, you have to assume the file was not created correctly, and should probably remove it.  You might want to check each output operation; that's the theoretically correct way to do it.  Obviously, you must check `fopen()` since you crash if you don't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Best practices in my eyes:

- Check every call to fopen, printf, puts, fprintf, fclose etc. for errors
- use getchar if you must, fread if you can
- use putchar if you must, fwrite if you can
- avoid arbitrary limits on input line length (might require malloc/realloc)
- know when you need to open output files in binary mode
- use Standard C, forget conio.h :-)
- newlines belong at the **end** of a line, not at the beginning of some text, i.e. it is `printf ("hello, world\n");` and not `"\nHello, world"` like those mislead by the Mighty William H. often write to cope with the sillyness of their command shell. Outputting newlines first breaks line buffered I/O.
- if you need more than 7bit ASCII, chose [Unicode](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/unicode.html) (the most common encoding is UTF-8 which is ASCII compatible). It's the last encoding you'll ever need to learn. Stay away from codepages and ISO-8859-*.

Comment: Can I ask why you say that `getchar` and `putchar` are functions that are only to be used "if we must"?

Comment: Basically it is just a preference for large chunk I/O versus character-by-character I/O. There is nothing inherently wrong with {get,put}char(). If you reimplement `cat`, using character I/O is obviously suboptimal.

Answer (score 4):

> Am I just completely overthinking this?

You are. If the task's simple, don't make a complicated solution on purpose just because it feels "more professional". While you're a beginner, focus on code readability, it will facilitate your and others' lives.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. I/O is fully buffered by default with `stdio` file functions, so you won't be writing to the file with every single call of `fprintf`. In fact, in many cases, nothing will be written to it until you call `fclose`.

It's good practice to check the return of `fopen`, to close your files when finished, etc. Let the OS and the compiler do their job in making the rest efficient, for simple programs like this.

Answer (score 0):

If no other program is checking for the presence of `~/program/csv/output.csv` for further processing, then what you're doing is just fine.

Otherwise you can consider writing to a `FILE *` obtained by a call to [`tmpfile` in stdio.h](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/c/stdio.h/tmpfile.php) or some similar library call, and when finished copy the file to the final destination. You could also put down a lock file `output.csv.lck` and remove that when you're done, but that depends on you being able to modify the other program's behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own `cat`, `cp`, `mv` programs for practice.